# grep stop at first match

Tags: awk, sed

I want to grep a file that stops at the first match, example:

```
${A57}${A17}${A23}${A20}${A35}${A57}${A33}${A24}${A38}${A38}${A24}${A17}${A57}${A33}${A23}${A38}${A18}${E52}${A28}${A28}${A28}${A25}${A38}${A22}${A50}${A30}${A57}${A37}${A18}${A44}${A15}${A28}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A14}
```

When I use `grep -o "${A57}.\*${A29}${A14}"` I obtain this output:

```
${A57}${A17}${A23}${A20}${A35}${A57}${A33}${A24}${A38}${A38}${A24}${A17}${A57}${A33}${A23}${A38}${A18}${E52}${A28}${A28}${A28}${A25}${A38}${A22}${A50}${A30}${A57}${A37}${A18}${A44}${A15}${A28}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A14}
```

Now my question is how can I stop grep with the first match of '${A57}' so that I have this output:

```
${A57}${A37}${A18}${A44}${A15}${A28}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A14}
```

Comment: In short, there is no way to restrict `.*` to not retrieve the longest possible match; that's what `*` _means._ Some regular expression tools like `grep -P` (if you have that) allow for non-greedy matching with `.*?`

Comment: In my opinion, this is not about greedy, but about avoiding a second occurrence of `${A57}` in the match.

Comment: @trincot It looks to me like they are trying to restrict the scope of `.*` one way or another. Given that we have to guess what these variables contain, there is really no good way to answer it without speculation. Perhaps the OP will want to [edit] to clarify what behavior exactly they are looking for, if indeed they don't think that the many answers to the duplicate solve their problem.

Comment: That is the right way but when I use the expression -P with ".*?" I obtain a blank output. 'grep --color=always -o -P "${A57}.*?${A29}${A14}"', some ideas?

Comment: Then that means there are no strings which match this expression. The exposition in your question can't really be true because the double quotes cause the shell to replace the values of the variables `A57`, `A29` etc with whatever those variables contain. Are you actually using single quotes around the search expression, or do the variables actually exist? If so, what do they contain?

Comment: This is not right from you because with a backslash at beginning the variable will not to be replaced. You can test it with: echo '${A57}${A17}${A23}${A20}${A35}${A57}${A33}${A24}${A38}${A38}${A24}${A17}${A57}${A33}${A23}${A38}${A18}${E52}${A28}${A28}${A28}${A25}${A38}${A22}${A50}${A30}${A57}${A37}${A18}${A44}${A15}${A28}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A14}' | grep --color=always -o "\${A57}.*\${A29}\${A14}"

Comment: Use sed and quit at the first occurrence `echo -e "a\nb\nc" | sed '/./q'`

Comment: @Nemsis always use single quotes unless you NEED double quotes, and always use double quotes unless you NEED no quotes. If you follow those rules you won't have to escape the `$`s.

Comment: Your question contains no backslashes before the dollar signs. If it's supposed to, please [edit] it.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use the wrong tool. Using any sed:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\(${A57}.*${A29}${A14}\).*/\1/p' file
${A57}${A37}${A18}${A44}${A15}${A28}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A14}
```

or an awk that supports `gensub()` such as GNU awk:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/.*(\${A57}.*\${A29}\${A14}).*/,"\\1",1)}' file
${A57}${A37}${A18}${A44}${A15}${A28}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A29}${A14}
```

Comment: Another question: Can you tell me how can I change this command, that the obtained output replace inside a value or file the text sequence like search and replace?

Comment: It's really not clear what your comment is trying to ask, and anyway, please don't pile on new requirements. This is already performing a search and replace; it's easy to add a second `sed` statement like `;s/foo/bar/` if you want to replace `foo` with `bar` in the result. If you need more help, please ask a new question, this time with a proper [mre]